# Web2py - Trying to get a value from a rows object without a 'for' sentence

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to edit the group membership for a user, I have in my controller:

```
def change_membership():

if request.vars.id:

    row = db(db.auth_membership.user_id == request.vars.id).select()
    id = row[0].id  
    form = SQLFORM(db.auth_membership,
                               id,
                               fields=['group_id'],
                               _action=URL()
                               )
if form.process().accepted:
    ...redirect back to user list

if form.errors:
    response.flash = 'form has errors'

return dict(form=form)
```

But It doesn't work, I get a :
 list index out of range

I know that only get one row, but I don't understand why its seems empty..

Thanks in advance
Christian

Comment: Where does request.vars.id get set and how is the value determined? Presumably it is added to the query string of the URL used to access this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent!

Thanks a lot Anthony and Massimo.

It´s save my day, now all is working using request.get_vars.id instead of request.vars.id

Reference:

2012/8/22 Anthony wrote:
Yes. Note, web2py stores GET variables in request.get_vars and POST variables in request.post_vars. It stores both GET and POST vars in request.vars. If both get_vars and post_vars have variables with the same name, it puts their values in a list within request.vars. Just change your code to use request.get_vars.id instead of request.vars.id.

2012/8/22 Massimo Di Pierro wrote:
You have two id fields. One in request.get_vars.id (from the url) and one in request.post_vars.id (from the form submission).